# Sending variables from objective C to url string

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am having problems with the code below trying to create a feedback form in my iPhone app and passing through a php mailer page and I wonder if the error below may be the cause.

The following code shows this problem 'Data argument not used by format string' refering to this `@"%@?email=%@&message="` in particular

```
NSString *email = [self.emailTxt text];
NSString *message = [self.messageTxt text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?email=%@&message=", FeedbackURL, email, message]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSString *title = (!error)? @"Message Sent" : @"Error";
    NSString *message = (!error)? @"Thank you for your Feedback, we hope it will help us to make this product even better." : @"There was an connection error. Please make sure you have internet connection and try again later.";
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];


if (email && (email.length > 0)) {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:email forKey:UserEmailKey];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the third `%@`.

```
@"%@?email=%@&message="
```

The third parameter is not filled in because you are missing a `%@`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a  `%@` in your format string:

```
@"%@?email=%@&message="
```

should be

```
@"%@?email=%@&message=%@"
```